Elasticsearch ShapeParser no more in ES8? Alternatives?
I was using ES7 ShapeParser which is no more supported in ES8 it seems:
def validateES(gf: GeoFeature): Unit = {
    val geom = Json.stringify(Json.toJson(gf.ftr.geometry))
    val parser = XContentType.JSON.xContent().createParser(null, null, geom)
    parser.nextToken()
    try {
      val parsed = ShapeParser.parse(parser)
      val shape = parsed.buildS4J()
    } catch {
      case ioe: IOException => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Invalid geometry: ${ioe.getMessage}")
    }
  }

Based on my understanding, I updated the code as follows:
def validateES(gf: GeoFeature): Unit = {
    val geom = Json.stringify(Json.toJson(gf.ftr.geometry))
    val parser = XContentType.JSON.xContent().createParser(XContentParserConfiguration.EMPTY, geom)
    parser.nextToken()
    try {
      val parsed = GeoShapeParser.parse(parser)
      val shape = parsed.buildS4J()
    } catch {
      case ioe: IOException => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Invalid geometry: ${ioe.getMessage}")
    }
  }

However I am not getting any method parse in GeoShapeParser. Can anyone help me figure out the right code when upgrading to es8?
Thanks in advance!
